# Get the value of a text in select tag

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm having issues getting the user selected text from the select tag. I've looked at the other similar questions but none really helps.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">


<select name="Select" id="vals" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="btn btn-warning">
    <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
                                    <?php
                                $user = new User();
      $sql5 = DB::getInstance()->get('country', array('user', '=', $user->data()->username));
                        if (!$sql5->count()) {
        echo 'No data';
    } else { 
        foreach ($sql5->results() as $sql5) {

    ?>
<option value="country"><?php echo $sql5->name;?></option>'; <?php
}}
?> 
                                </select>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

The dropdown has a list of countries assigned to the user but when I click on it to output details on the country, nothing shows.

```
                        <?php
                            if (isset($_POST['Select']) && !empty($_POST['Select'])) {

                                $userSelection =  $_POST['Select'];
     $sql = DB::getInstance()->get('country',array('country', '=', $userSelection));
     if (!$sql->count()) {
                                echo 'no data';
                            } else {
                                foreach ($sql->results() as $sql) {
    echo 'data'; }
```

The query gets the data of the country selected from the country table. When I change the $userSelection in the query to a specific country name, the data for that country shows. I think the problem might be the option value within the select tag but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is the same on all requests. Update to

```
<option value="<?php echo $sql5->country ?>"><?php echo $sql5->name;?></option>
```

This is assuming the identifying column is `country` since that is your where clause in the select query.